# How install custom wordpress setup on openshift server

Tags: wordpress, cloud, remote-access, openshift, filezilla

i installed standard wordpress setup on openshift using create an application options.WordPress application automatically chose the correct cartridges (dependencies) for the application (PHP and MySQL).which is ideal if you build a site from scratch. but i have custom wordpress installation setup, how i install this on server and link it to php and mysql.i use [fillezilla to acess server files](http://www.codersgrid.com/2013/07/16/openshift-wordpress-ftp/) please tell way i implement it with filezilla.i never use git before. so please tell alternate ways that based on ui wizard not command one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for posting to our forums as well.  See https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/how-install-custom-wordpress-setup-on-openshift-server